# How to call a complex Oracle Procedure from PHP Code

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

Please help me to fix the below issue.

**Intro:**
I have made a custom MVC framework where I made a method which will call "Oracle Stored procedure". So now I am able to establish the connection with the PHP-OCI module and can able to fetch and insert records and also able to call a simple hello-world procedure. But I am having a long procedure that has In and Out params but I could not able to call that procedure.

**Problem:**
When I directly call that procedure in SQL editor and run it, its working. But when I call from PHP it's giving me an error.

1. I call the procedure from SQL editor like below:

```
DECLARE
    V_HOSPITAL_CODE VARCHAR2(200);
    V_SPECIALTY_ID  NUMBER;
    V_refcur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    lsn1 NUMBER;
    lsn2 VARCHAR2(200);
    lsn3 VARCHAR2(200);

BEGIN
    V_HOSPITAL_CODE := 'ABC';
    V_SPECIALTY_ID  := 1;
    SP_DOCTORS_LIST( V_HOSPITAL_CODE => V_HOSPITAL_CODE, V_SPECIALTY_ID => V_SPECIALTY_ID, V_REFCUR => V_refcur );
    loop
        FETCH V_refcur into lsn1,lsn2,lsn3; 
        exit when V_refcur%notfound;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lsn1 || ' | ' || lsn2 || ' | ' || lsn3);
    end loop;
    CLOSE V_REFCUR;
END;
```

Note: Above procedure runs successfully

2. PHP Code to call the Procedure:

```
        $sql = 'BEGIN SP_PATIENT_DATA(:V_HOSPITAL_CODE, :V_PATIENTID, :V_REFCUR); END;';
        $stmt = oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        // Assign a value to the input
        $V_HOSPITAL_CODE = 'ABC';
        $V_PATIENTID = 24;
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':V_HOSPITAL_CODE', $V_HOSPITAL_CODE);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':V_PATIENTID', $V_PATIENTID);
        oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':V_REFCUR', $V_REFCUR);
        oci_execute($stmt);
        print "$V_REFCUR\n";
```

**The above code gives me the below error**

```
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_PATIENT_DATA' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in /var/www/html/project/app/Components/Connection.php on line 72
```

PHP: 7.4
OS: Ubuntu 20
Oracle: 11g

Thanks and Regards
Tanmaya

Answer (score 0):

Change your REF CURSOR bind to something like

```
$V_REFCUR = oci_new_cursor($conn);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':V_REFCUR', $V_REFCUR, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
```

See the PHP OCI8 documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-cursor.php for one example.

Another example is:

```
<?php

/*

  Example using a REF CURSOR to return query results from a stored
  procedure.

  Create this package before running this PHP script:

    create or replace
      procedure myproc(p1 out sys_refcursor) as
    begin
      open p1 for
        select last_name from employees where rownum <= 5;
    end;
    /
*/

$c = oci_connect('cj', 'cj', 'localhost/orclpdb1');

$stmtarray = array(
    "create or replace
      procedure myproc(p1 out sys_refcursor) as
    begin
      open p1 for
        select last_name from employees where rownum <= 5;
    end;"
);

foreach ($stmtarray as $stmt) {
    $s = oci_parse($c, $stmt);
    $r = oci_execute($s);
    if (!$r) {
        $m = oci_error($s);
        if ($m['code'] != 942) {  // ignore table or view doesn't exist
            echo $m['message'], "\n";
        }
    }
}

// Excute the call to the PL/SQL stored procedure
$stid = oci_parse($c, "call myproc(:rc)");
$refcur = oci_new_cursor($c);
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':rc', $refcur, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($stid);

// Execute and fetch from the cursor
oci_execute($refcur);
echo '<table border="1">';
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($refcur)) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach ($row as $c) {
    echo "<td>$c</td>\n";
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

If the REF CURSOR contains a lot of rows, don't forget to tune the prefetch size.

More information is in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/php/201212-ug-php-oracle-1884760.pdf)